# Got 'TypeError: error.status is not a function' after specific route call

Tags: node.js, express

The error comes only after this route call, the others works:

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
User.find({ email: req.body.email })
  .exec()
  .then(user => {
    if (user.length >= 1) {
      return res.status(409).json({
        message: "Mail exists"
      });
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            error: err
    
          });
        } else {
          const user = new User({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash
        
          });
          user
            .save()
            .then(result => {
              console.log(result);
              res.status(201).json({
                message: "User created"
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(500).json({
                error: err
              });

            });
        }
      });
    }
  });});
```

This is the handling error middleware:

```
app.use((error,req, res, next) => {
res.status(error.status || 500);
res.json({
    error:{
        message: error.message
    }
})
console.log(error);});
```

I found many similar issue on stackoverflow, github etc... but the solutions didn't worked.
I'm current using the 10.19.0 Node version.

```
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.13.8",
"morgan": "^1.10.0"}
```

Full stacktrace as requested, i initially tought it might be a dependency conflict, but i had no idea how to deal with it.

```
TypeError: error.status is not a function
at app.use (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/app.js:41:11)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at app.use (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/app.js:33:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at /home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
at invokeCallback (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
at done (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/edo/Scrivania/backend/node-rest-api/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
```

Comment: Nothing in the snippet you shared treats `error.status` as a function. Can you share the full stacktrace? Something is missing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the error, my mistake(huge), I was just calling the wrong endpoint during API test with Postman.

```
localhost:5000/signup
```

instead of:

```
localhost:5000/user/signup
```